# Wall content on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

What I want is to be able to put the wall content of my facebook page in my website. I want to include the posts and comments of others and mines.

I have 2 questions:

1. Activity feed:

Here is what the FB docs say :

```
<fb:activity 
site="jerrycain.com"
action="critiqueapp:despise,critiqueapp:review,critiqueapp:grade">
</fb:activity>
```

Where can I get a list of all possible actions? Can I specify that I want posts and comments?

1. OpenGraph:

I was able to get an access token yesterday, that is not valid anymore. I was able to see a json object of the wall content. What is the best way to have this permanently?

Answer (score 1):

Activity feed social plugin is using OpenGraph actions in `action` field so the complete list is simply not available due to possibility to create custom actions for every application, there is several [Built-in Action Types](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/):

- [Watch](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#watch) - Video, Movie, TV Show, or TV Episode
- [Read](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read) - Article

Currently specifying `like` also works but it's not documented. Aside of those pre-defined actions you may [Define Actions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/). Neither posts or comments is listed as supported actions in documentation.

---

[Access tokens are expired](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/) and [need to be extended](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/#extend_token) if you need longer life-time of a token. Also you may use [application `access_token`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin) to access public posts from your page (without need to get the token from user)...

Comment: Hi, I created an app and got my app id and secret. and was able to get an access token by typing this: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=myclientid&client_secret=myclientsecret&grant_type=client_credentials. I have a doubt regarding client_credentials if typing it as it is or typing my credentials is the right thing to do. For now the json returned does not contain posts and comments of other poeple it shows just mines. Here is the url I am typing to get the json: https://graph.facebook.com/myfbid/feed?access_token=access_token_generated. Any suggestions?